# How to optimize initiative?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, initiative

I want to make initiative the highest possible for a level 1 character in Pathfinder. Here's what I got:

+5 DEX 20 (18 plus race)
+4 Improved Initiative (feat)
+4 Familiar (compy or scorpion)
+2 Trait (reactionary or elf trait)
+2 Fleet-footed elf  (alternate race feature)

+17 Total

Anything I'm missing? Magic items or spells perhaps?

Comment: Is wealth pumping allowed?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I wouldn't think so for level 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few more options for permanent initiative buffs level 1:

- The [Divination](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/divination) wizard school grants an initiative bonus (+1 at level 1)
- If you take the [Rich Parents](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/social-traits/rich-parents) trait you can afford a [Cracked Dusty Rose Prism](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/dusty-rose-prism-ioun-stone)
- If you are just interested in initiative you can also be an [Ifrit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-ifrit) with Wildfire Heart (+4 initiative) instead of a fleet footed elf. (It is worth noting that I would not endorse this for a generally optimized wizard but you will have more initiative)
- The [Young](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/young-characters) template will give you +2 dexterity. I don't know of a way to be both young and a wizard but if you can get there (maybe some sort of age reversal) you could have an additional +1 initiative

I assume you are not interested in temporary buffs but there are also a wide variety of potions you could drink (as noted by lithas).

Comment: To add, there is also the [Young Template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/young-characters) which will give an additional +2 Dexterity (+1 Initiative). Of course this would restrict classes, but I've had some GMs disregard that as boring.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you can boost your dex a little more. Try getting [Reduced](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/reducePerson.html) to start with, and then see if you can drink a potion of [Cat's Grace](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cat-s-grace).